# How to understand BGP Announcements on Cloudflare Radar?

Tags: bgp

See the "BGP Announcements" card on any AS page. Example: https://radar.cloudflare.com/routing/AS13335

I fail to reproduce the same numbers with my own tool when I use a single location from [routeviews](http://archive.routeviews.org/route-views.kixp/bgpdata/2023.10/RIBS/) MRT dumps.

Do they count any of the 8 [possible subtypes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6396#section-5.4) as 1 annoucement?
Do they count one annoucement per prefix in a single UPDATE message?

Their documentation [fails](https://developers.cloudflare.com/radar/glossary/#bgp-announcements) to precise this.

Comment: I use the 20231024.1600 RIB dumps, and also included any updates file in the 16:00-17:59 time range.